# Problem enabling memory view in stm32 eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, stm32

I am having problem with enabling memory view to work in eclipse. It seems that it's disabled and i couldn't find a way to make it work. + icon in the Monitors section of the memory pane also doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: Do you pause the program execution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your program execution to see the memory